# Put FBLoginView in ViewDidLoad crash the app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have put Facebook loginview code like this

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create Login View so that the app will be granted "status_update" permission.
    loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
    loginview.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [loginview sizeToFit];


  }
```

on first time when i logged in it works fine.But after logged in when i jump to this view from another view it crash the app.

What is the problem?I didn't get it.

Comment: What is the crash log and do you use loginView in viewWillAppear as well?

Comment: i have also put it in viewWillAppear but same problem.[FBLoginView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance .I have not release this object and even in .h file i have write (nonatomic,retain) FBLoginView *loginview

Comment: What you are using for Facebook login. Share Kit or facebook SDK?

Comment: @MinkleGarg facebook sdk

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem.  I fixed it by doing this:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // This isn't public, so you need to use performSelector...
    [fbLoginView performSelector:@selector(unwireViewForSession)]; 
}
```

This is based on a bug report here:
https://github.com/buzztabapp/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/2301de144958a5502f9dae0a1bb7c234873581ba

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   ...
   static id sharedInstance = self;
   loginview.delegate = sharedInstance;
   ...
}
```

By creating your delegate view instance as static, you store it in the same scope than the facebook login view (which is created in static scope). You avoid bad access error.

Answer (score 0):

I have quit a same problem while dismissing ViewController with FBLoginView.
I solved this problem by setting `FBLoginView` delegate to nil before calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

```
...
self.loginFBView.delegate = nil;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```